# Add client name in custom routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to add the client name in each and every route in my .net core application. I do not want to add in each controller using Route OR RoutePrefix. It should be available for all controllers. So,how can I do this ?

Lets say I have following routes

1. mysite.com/virtualdir1/clientname/Login
2. mysite.com/virtualdir1/clientname/Dashboard
3. mysite.com/virtualdir1/clientname/Home
4. mysite.com/virtualdir1/clientname/AboutUs

I have tried to setup in startup.cs file as follows but it gives 404 error

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Backend",
                    template: "{clientname}/{controller=Home}/{action=Login}");

            });
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Your route says there should be a controller in the URL and you're not giving it. You probably want to remove that from the URL template.

Comment: So which is the most preferred way whether we should include controller OR not ?

Comment: It's your choice. If you want it in the URL, put it in the URL. If you don't, don't put it there. But it has to match. Currently you clearly don't want it in there if you want to have just `{clientname}/{action}`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yeah now I have added the controller name and its working ! But why this route is not followed by other controllers ? for other controllers it is not including the client name only action and controller name ? I want client name in every request for all controllers/action methods